# Taking much time to download & display images from url to Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have 20 URL of different images. I need to download the 20 images from the URL and display it in Grid view. For me its taking much time to download the image content. Following is the code i'm using in Image Adapter class.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1,0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(GetDrawableImage(url));
    return imageView;
}
private Drawable GetDrawableImage(String zurlP)
{   InputStream InputStreamL = null;
    Drawable DrawableImageL = null;  
try {
        InputStreamL = (InputStream) new URL(zurlP).getContent();
        DrawableImageL = Drawable.createFromStream(InputStreamL, "src");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {          
    } catch (IOException e) {           
    }  
    return DrawableImageL;
}
```

Is there any easiest way(Less Time Consuming) to perform the same task?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.., You can use Asynctask or Painless threading to load large images from server. And Cache the Images once you download. You can use [Fedor lazylist] for that (https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

**Various possibilities.**

[Multi Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

[Cacheing](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

[Pain less threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

[Large bitmaps loading](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

**Or** you can simply go with thumb nails. Means get thumb nails from server instead of bit images. Loading will be effective

Comment: Thumbnails are a very good idea especially if you are dealing with source images in the 10s or 100s of KB, but do combine them with the other techniques suggested here, it's not an either/or.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download images in other thread. You can use [image loader](https://web.archive.org/web/20130518150136/http://androidimageloader.com/).